# Increasing MySQL server timeout value

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a find() call which sometimes takes a long time to complete, depending on the date range selected by the user. This can sometimes cause the server to time out (2006: MySQL server has gone away), causing the find() to fail. I have tried altering the timeout value using the following:
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 5);

My presumption is that this is failing because I cannot override the server settings on the hosting package.
I was advised by the hosting company to use the following code:
SET @@session.wait_timeout=60

I would be very grateful for any advice on increasing the MySQL server timeout through CakePHP.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the PHP script that times out?

Comment: I'd say you should think about a different strategy to find these results, and/or heavily optimize that query and the database. Do you really want to have the *user* wait that long for the page to load?

Answer (score 0):

i guess you should increase php request timeout rather then mysql timeout

```
set_time_limit(250);
```

Comment: I tried that without any luck @NarayaN, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Viswanathan Iyer -No, 'set_time_limit()' didn't work for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider another approach.
Because php run by apache will timeout, although you can set it a large value(however, some hosting prohibit to do so).
You can try to submit the form by AJAX when user request the data. And using some backend technology(node.js) to connect to mysql and query the data. Then send back to front end.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Magic. Your suggestion sounds like a good solution but I was hoping to find an easier fix.

Comment: The easier and right solution is pagination. Page your respond data.